# How can I access get only the dates in a list? python

Tags: python, arrays, django, list

I wrote this code:

```
lastDay = Borrowing.objects.values('end_date')
print("the list is: ",lastDay)
```

The output is

```
the list is:  <QuerySet [{'end_date': datetime.date(2022, 9, 30)}, {'end_date': datetime.date(2021, 7, 26)}, {'end_date': datetime.date(2021, 9, 26)}]>
```

i need only the dates, how can i get rid of `{'end_date': datetime.date()}`

Answer (score 0):

You can format the dates properly, so:

```
lastDay = Borrowing.objects.values_list('end_date', flat=True)
data = [x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for x in lastDay]
```